# Deleting the Unnamed columns in the data frame generates errors

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to delete the **Unnamed** columns in the following data frame `df` (to download from [this link](https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/earnings-place-residence-borough)):

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('./earnings-residence-borough.xlsx', sheet_name='Total, weekly', skiprows=[1, 2], header=0)
df1.head(5)
```

[image]

```
print(df.columns)
```

Out:

```
Index([       'Code',        'Area',          2002,  'Unnamed: 3',
                2003,  'Unnamed: 5',          2004,  'Unnamed: 7',
                2005,  'Unnamed: 9',          2006],
      dtype='object')
```

Can someone help? Thanks.

I have tried several methods and I get errors, eg.:

- Solution 1:

  `df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]`

Out:

```
`TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'Index'`
```

- Solution 2:

  `remove_cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'Unnamed' in col] df.drop(remove_cols, axis='columns', inplace=True)`

Out:

```
`TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`
```

- Solution 3:

  `df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('Unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)`

Out:

```
ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')
```

Out:

```
Index([False, False,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,
         nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,
         nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,
         nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,   nan,  True,
         nan,  True],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to solve your problem.

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns.values if 'Unnamed' not in str(col)]
df = df[cols]
```

Comment: Thanks but I get `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable` as well.

Comment: I've updated the data source from a url link and code to read excel file to help u to test.

Comment: I could not download your data, it gives error.

Comment: Sorry, I updated url, you may find `earnings-residence-borough.xlsx` to download on that page.

Comment: Some of your columns are integer not string. So we need to change it to string before checking 'Unnamed' keyword. I edited the code, now it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason. So the column names' datatype could not be integer?

Comment: They can be integer, but you need to check its type before performing such operation.

Comment: So if the elements of the list are integers, we can't use list comprehension directly, right?

Answer (score 0):

The only code I've found so far that solves this problem:

`df.drop(df.filter(regex="Unname"), axis=1, inplace=True)`